# I can't run any react app with iOS simulator

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios, yarnpkg, react-native-cli

from 3, 4 days to today i can't run any app with ios simulator using `react-native run-ios`the app exists without any error message and refuses to run. running `react-native log-ios` this come in stderr

```
coms[7364] <Error>: assertion failed: 16G29 14E8301: libxpc.dylib + 64131 [624BAF4F-2E03-34F8-ACBA-970B04637786]: 0x7d
Unknown[7364] <Error>: 
coms[7364] <Notice>: Initializing <RCTCxxBridge: 0x6000001a2d80> (parent: <RCTBridge: 0x6000000a1ce0>, executor: (null))
coms[7364] <Warning>: Class RCTCxxModule was not exported. Did you forget to use RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()?
coms[7364] <Notice>: Running application coms ({
        initialProps =     {
        };
        rootTag = 1;
    })
coms[7364] <Error>: -[NSTaggedPointerString unsignedIntValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa313537323930327
coms[7364] <Error>: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSTaggedPointerString unsignedIntValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa313537323930327'
    *** First throw call stack:
    (
        0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d419b0b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
        1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010c2cf141 objc_exception_throw + 48
        2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d489134 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
        3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d3a0840 ___forwarding___ + 1024
        4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d3a03b8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
        5   coms                                0x000000010b6a70d4 -[RCTMultipartStreamReader emitProgress:contentLength:final:callback:] + 244
        6   coms                                0x000000010b6a78ca -[RCTMultipartStreamReader readAllPartsWithCompletionCallback:progressCallback:] + 1610
        7   coms                                0x000000010b6f71fc -[RCTMultipartDataTask URLSession:streamTask:didBecomeInputStream:outputStream:] + 444
        8   CFNetwork                           0x000000010ce79c51 __88-[NSURLSession delegate_streamTask:didBecomeInputStream:outputStream:completionHandler:]_block_invoke + 51
        9   Foundation                          0x000000010bdd93b7 __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 7
        10  Foundation                          0x000000010bdd90bb -[NSBlockOperation main] + 101
        11  Foundation                          0x000000010bdd7877 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 627
        12  Foundation                          0x000000010bdd35fc __NSOQSchedule_f + 198
        13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001110f4792 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
        14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001110da237 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 1022
        15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001110da98f _dispatch_queue_invoke + 1053
        16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001110dc899 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 813
        17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001110dc50d _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 113
        18  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001114885a2 _pthread_wqthread + 1299
        19  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000011148807d start_wqthread + 13
    )
SpringBoard[3413] <Error>: [KeyboardArbiter] HW kbd: Failed to set (null) as keyboard focus
com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.E2457C7B-7E39-4B0A-B1C4-0FF23CDB1193.launchd_sim[3395] (UIKitApplication:org.reactjs.native.example.coms[0xeff5][3418][7364]) <Notice>: Service exited due to Abort trap: 6
backboardd[3414] <Error>: [Common] Unable to get short BSD proc info for 7364: No such process
backboardd[3414] <Error>: [Common] Unable to get proc info for 7364: Undefined error: 0
assertiond[3418] <Warning>: Deleted job with label: UIKitApplication:org.reactjs.native.example.coms[0xeff5][3418]
```

i can't run any code still the default one that comes with `react-native init XXXX`. i'm out of ideas.

What have i tried:

- Create new project
- delete all the cache and data
- delete setting and reset the data in the iOS Simulator
- uninstall node with npm and installing again with yarn
- reinstall all components with yarn (react-native-cli, node, and dependences)
- reset the yarn cache and npm cache
- delete .rncache
- obviously uninstall the app from iOS simulator

Comment: Did you create new project and try it to run as an empty app without any modification? And one more thing, did you try to create and app with [create-react-native-app tool](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app)? May be one of these give you and idea on what is wrong.

Comment: Btw, if you decide to use `create-react-native-app`, do not forget to `eject` it by running `npm run eject`. Ejecting gives you standard `react-native` folder structure.

Comment: @alix to your first question the answer is Yes and still have the same sympthoms ,and the later one yes it runs with create-react-native-app and ejecting it ... Weird still don't know what happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in react-native-cli v0.48.0, this was fixed in 0.48.1